# Linking my Django docker container to a postgres container

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I create a django docker application image.
in my django app, in settings.py DATABASE entry is:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'cath_local',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
    'HOST': 'postgres',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
    },
}
}
```

well, at this point i create my docker image using `docker build` command; all done.
Before running my django app docker image i run:

```
docker run -it postgres
```

image is downloaded and container start correctly

[image]

but when i run my django app

```
docker run -it cath2019/cathedral_studio:latest
```

but wher python manage.py runserver command into my Dockerfile start i get this error:

> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name does not resolve

here my app Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache make linux-headers libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
#RUN apk update && apk add build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev
RUN mkdir /Code
WORKDIR /Code
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /Code/

ENTRYPOINT python /Code/core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

How can i connect into my django settings DATABASE to running postgres container?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: You might be able to set it to [`10.0.2.2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621207/1324033) but you'll have to map the port when running postgres too, I'd recommend keeping it as it is and just using a docker-compose file

Comment: It would be better to use docker-compose to start the two containers together and putting them on the same network.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two methods to solve this:

**1. User defined networks**

> The default bridge network is present on all Docker hosts. If you do
>   not specify a different network, new containers are automatically
>   connected to the default bridge network.

[Link](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network)

You can get IP address of containers using `docker network inspect bridge`.
Then you can use the IP address from containers attribute.

This is not recommended as changes in container might change the ip
address.

> Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the
>   default bridge network. If you want containers to be able to resolve
>   IP addresses by container name, you should use user-defined networks
>   instead. You can link two containers together using the legacy docker run --link option, but this is not recommended in most cases.

To Create a network run `docker network create --driver bridge django_network`.

Then attach both the containers to same network using
`docker run -it postgres --network=django_network` and
`docker run -it cath2019/cathedral_studio:latest --network=django_network`.

Now you can connect to postgres database from your django app using hostname.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'cath_local',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
    'HOST': 'postgres',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'OPTIONS': {
      'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
    },
}
```

}

**2. Docker-compose**

Have a look at official documentation [Link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) to dockerize a django app.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using only Docker**

You would need to link the Django container using: `--link postgres:postgres`

Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26296462/1223945)

**Using Docker Compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/