# Linking Django - Postgresql with Standalone Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, networking, docker-network

Following the thread [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295061/linking-django-and-postgresql-with-docker/26296462#26296462), I am trying to run Django in one container, Postgres in another container, and connect them "manually" via user-defined networks.

I first create the containers:

```
docker run --rm --name postgres-10 \
    -d -it \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    --network django-network \
    postgres:10

docker run --rm --name betcomm-django \
    -d -it  \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -v $PWD:/app/backend \
    --network django-network \
    --link postgres-10:docker-db \
    pablorr10/betcomm-django:dev
```

This is my network after launching both containers:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "django-network",
        "Id": "bbae9d656ea9ccc56c2c0f4db310d53fa135275358b16bc08636cf0c1a56127f",
        "Created": "2020-03-15T17:21:48.405473202Z",
        ...

        "Containers": {
            "79c7a66a5f4a892486d3c1d3089ff5850e2753af66cc694798015f80021297f3": {
                "Name": "postgres-10",
                "EndpointID": "d5fb80edfdf19678890da858e25e8bafd3e56113f82a5c1e39de5ca16f1caf5a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8873f054b23bb888b91deb64c819c1bf370db6ddc7b9f638ee60d850ee082da6": {
                "Name": "betcomm-django",
                "EndpointID": "e60640ec4dfbc1dd86b3464260ed73446846b8dd33b6e4b173befe26d5ee0738",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },...
]
```

And this is the error on the Django container:

```
root@8873f054b23b:/app/backend# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Running Docker locally, setting env variables...

DB:  betcomm-dev
User:  postgres
Pass:  postgres
Host:  docker-db
Port:  5432
Running Docker locally, setting env variables...

DB:  betcomm-dev
User:  postgres
Pass:  postgres
Host:  docker-db
Port:  5432
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    ...
    ...
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "docker-db" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

But docker-db on that IP is indeed connected.

These are the logs of the postgres container:

```
(django) ➜  backend git:(serializing-on-kubernetes) ✗ docker logs postgres-10
2020-03-15 20:39:09.678 CET [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-03-15 20:39:09.679 CET [1] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Cannot assign requested address
2020-03-15 20:39:09.679 CET [1] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2020-03-15 20:39:09.686 CET [1] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "192.168.65.2": Cannot assign requested address
2020-03-15 20:39:09.686 CET [1] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2020-03-15 20:39:09.686 CET [1] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "docker.for.mac.localhost"
2020-03-15 20:39:09.688 CET [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-03-15 20:39:09.808 CET [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-03-15 20:38:56 CET
2020-03-15 20:39:09.843 CET [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If two containers share the same network you can connect one to another using the container `name`.

For example:

```sh
docker run -it  --name this-is-postgres --network=django-network  postgres
docker run -it  --name this-is-django --network=django-network  python3
```

Both containers have a shared network, called `django-network`, and to get the resources contained in the postgress container you can use its container name: `this-is-postgres`.

In django settings, for example:

```py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "mydb",
        "USER": "pg",
        "PASSWORD": "Password123",
        "HOST": "this-is-postgres", # the container name!
        "PORT": 5432,
    },
}
```

Edit:

if you can connect to the network the problem comes from a wrong configuration of the database and/or the database you are trying to connect does not exist. The following `docker run` is compatible with the previous Django settings database configuration. The env variables are used to set username, password and to create a database called `mydb`.

```sh
docker run -it  --name this-is-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Password123 -e POSTGRES_USER=pg -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb --network=django-network  postgres
```

For the complete list of commands/env variables see https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: It is able to recognize again the IP given the container name, but still can't connect to the database...

psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "postgres-10" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Can you use docker-compose? Edit: is the database created? Did you set the postgres ENV variables?

Comment: I am trying to learn how it works without compose / kubectl.
I have appended to the question how I run the containers, I forgot it

Comment: Could you please provide me the `docker run` you are using?

Comment: It is working! Thanks for your help! I am reading the documentation, do you think this could have been the problem?

--> Note 1: The PostgreSQL image sets up trust authentication locally so you may notice a password is not required when connecting from localhost (inside the same container). However, a password will be required if connecting from a different host/container.  <--

Comment: Actually I have noticed something.
If I don't mount the volume  """-v /Users/pabloruizruiz/Docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data \"" where I am trying to use data from my local Postgresql installation, everything breaks again, even though the database name is the same!.